# Laravel Task Scheduling Error: Invalid CRON field value 10,40 at position

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I was trying to schedule a job to run on 10th and 40th minute of every hour. So wrote the expression as follows:

```
$schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\ExcuteJob())->cron('0 10,40 * * *');
```

And getting error:

> Invalid CRON field value 10,40 at position 1 {"exception":"[object]
>   (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Invalid CRON field value 10,40 at
>   position 1 at
>   /var/www/html/school-management-system/vendor/dragonmantank/cron-expression/src/Cron/CronExpression.php:154)

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your command try this:

```
$schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\ExcuteJob())->cron('*/10,*/40 */1 * * *');
```

This command should call the cronjob every 10th and 40th minutes of an hour.

This [page](https://crontab.guru) may help you.

Comment: It's not working as well. Showing error `Invalid CRON field value */10,*/40 at position 0`